# Multiple Choice Many-to-Many

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

There is a class

```
class Trip {

    static constraints = {
        sTrip(blank: true, nullable: true)
    }

    static hasMany = [trip: Trip]
    static belongsTo = [sTrip: Trip]

    String name

    String toString() {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

I need to add an optional field in which I can select the data already available for this class.

That is, many-to-many relationships with the class itself
I did this:

```
static hasMany = [trip: Trip]
static belongsTo = [sTrip: Trip]
```

But from displays only a drop-down list

How can I submit a multiple list?

Comment: Are you using scaffolding?

Comment: No, I even rewrote the standard data mapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `multiple="true"` attribute to your select e.g.

```
<g:select multiple="true" name="item" id="item" from="['item1', 'item2', 'item3']" />
```

Then in your controller/service:

```
params.list( 'item' ).each {
    println it
}
```